# How to setup HTTP Routing Mesh (HRM) in docker datacenter community edition?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network, docker-ingress

There is a way to setup HRM in docker datacenter EE. But, I would like to know if the same thing possible in community edition?

If yes then how? And no then is there any substitute to achieve the similar capability to route incoming traffic from port `80/443` to ingress network?

Comment: There is no support for HRM in community edition. Not clear how routing incoming traffic from port 80/443 to ingress network would help?